# exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_'

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, gradle

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open project generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\InFED Laptop\Documents\GitHub\sustain-and-save\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\InFED Laptop.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\cgusqz2rdd56uogb1dahk58km).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same bug, and I found that the bug is caused by non compatibility of gradle user.

And the following works for me :

- Check the compatibility [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).
- Then go to the files `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
- Set the attribute `distributionUrl` with the compatible version of gradle

Run the project and now you are okay

Answer (score 1):

Please check gradle compatibility from here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html and use the compatible version.

I'm using java `19.0.1`. Updating Gradle version as below can solve the issue:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
```

Cleaning gradle before retrying is also helpful:

```
gradle clean
```

Comment: This worked for me. But first check the java --version