# exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63 in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

full error:-
ould not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\Scripts\6valley-130nulled\codecanyon-31448597-6valley-multivendor-ecommerce-complete-ecommerce-mobile-app-web-and-admin-panel\Seller app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\patel.gradle\caches\7.3.3\scripts\w7tvtrqqgo1fid1ul2396x86).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

this code is located in setting.gradle:-

include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"

i want try run program in my android device.

Comment: Have you tried a [web search](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=Unsupported+class+file+major+version+63&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug, and I fix it.
You can follow the steps I already wrote in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75653626/15721679).